# PHP json_encode return rows as arrays instead of objects

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, json

From my experience, when I json_encode data from a mysql table, the output is an object containing each row as an object within. What I want to do is to get each row as an array, like the example below (don't need the column names in there). How can I do that?

```
{ "Data": [
    ["1","Internet Explorer 4.0","Win 95+","4","X","1"],
    ["2","Internet Explorer 5.0","Win 95+","5","C","2"],
    ["3","Internet Explorer 5.5","Win 95+","5.5","A","3"],
    ["4","Internet Explorer 6","Win 98+","6","A","4"],
] }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`mysql_fetch_row` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php) to get each row. This will get a row as a numerical array and those are also encoded as JSON arrays:

```
$data = array();

while(($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))) {
    $data[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode(array('Data' => $data));
```

Comment: Where is $result defined?

Comment: Where is $result defined? [2]

Comment: @FlipNovid: `$result` is the result of running a query. If you look at the documentation I linked to you can see an example.

Answer (score 0):

NOT CHECKED in interpreter:
You can change the type of variable by simple types convertion:

```
$data = DB::get('SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE 1');
echo json_encode(array('Data' => (array)$data));
```

Also you can use next function: array mysql_fetch_array ( resource $result [, int $result_type ] )

Comment: DB abstraction. You can use it as $data = mysql_fetch_array($mysql_result, MYSQL_NUM); Just convert object to array. It must help.